# Reactjs datatable with tree grid support

Tags: reactjs, datatable, treegrid

any suggestion for a native reactjs component that supports 
treegrid grouping such as https://datatables.net//forums/discussion/37920 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I can help you. Correct me if I am not fully understand your question. I use [react-bootstrap-table](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/index.html). which is easy to use, but you need to take care of the CSS global element. I got some bugs before, I recommend use the CSS module to solve these CSS conflict.

Comment: thks for the tip, I use it as well but unfortunately it does not handle (yet) the treegrid view mode (meaning having child row from a parent row) https://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/treegrid/examples/example02_test_performance.html

Comment: I think that might help you, they add a new feature called expend the row: https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/blob/master/examples/js/expandRow/expandRow.js

Comment: that is close to the need indeed but I don't think they have a selectable subrow option do they?

Comment: I think they has expand component, the attribute is expand Component, which can expand the row and get another subtable BSTable. I could not try right now, But I will also try it after I go back home.